# What kinds of resolution or other software incompatibilities can exist between a screen and a computer?

Tags: display, tv

I'm looking for a screen to connect to a computer. Since this computer gets used as a TV, I might want quite a large screen - probably a TV rather than a monitor.

Of course the computer needs to be physically capable of connecting to the screen (ie. have the right kind of port - VGA or HDMI), but what about software or video-card related issues? Specifically, I'm wondering if it might happen that the computer can't output a high enough resolution to produce a nice image on the screen, if the screen is too large. Or can the computer display any kind of resolution demanded of it? Are there other potential incompatibilities I should be worrying about?

Comment: This will be largely determined by your video card and its drivers. what kind of hardware and OS are in use?

Comment: @FrankThomas It's a Windows 8 machine, a tower. I'm not sure what kind of video card (if any) are in there. What specific information should I look for?

Comment: the model, and its max resolution. tools like speccy or sandra or CPUZ should be able to tell you the model number, so you can look it up online.